# firebase: update table data on client side every minute using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Created a fake train schedule to try to learn firebase. communication between page and server is good however I want the times to update on the client side web page every minute but only the times. The times are displayed in a table.

```
//pull from database and prints to screen/html
trainDataBase.ref().on("child_added", function (childSnapshot) {

    console.log("childSnapshot", childSnapshot.val());

    // Store everything into a variable.
    var trainName = childSnapshot.val().tname;
    var destination = childSnapshot.val().dest;
    var firstTrainTime = childSnapshot.val().firstTime;
    var frequency = childSnapshot.val().freq;

    // Minute Until Train
    var tMinutesTillTrain = frequency - tRemainder;
    console.log("MINUTES TILL TRAIN: " + tMinutesTillTrain);

    // Next Train
    var nextTrain = moment().add(tMinutesTillTrain, "minutes");
    console.log("ARRIVAL TIME: " + moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm"));
    nextTrainConverted = moment(nextTrain).format("hh:mm A")

    $("#train-table > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + trainName + "</td><td>" + destination + "</td><td>" + frequency + " Minutes" + "</td><td>" + tMinutesTillTrain + " Minutes" + "</td><td>" + nextTrainConverted + "</td><td>" + '<button class="update">Update</button>' + "</td></td>" + "</td><td>" + '<button class="remove">Remove</button>' + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Just want to update the train times and minutes till next train.

Comment: Look into using a newer framework/library such as `angular` or `react`. If you want to stick with jquery perhaps add an `setInterval` that constantly updates the train information.

Comment: Yeah set interval causes issues and have not gotten into angular JS